# How would I devise code to get both within subject and between subject comparisons when attempting to carry out a repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

I understand I can use lmer but I would like to undertake a repeated measures anova in order to carry out both a within group and a between group analysis. 
So I am trying to compare the difference in metabolite levels between three groups ( control, disease 1 and disease 2) over time ( measurements collected at two timepoints), and to also make a within group comparison, comparing time point 1 with time point 2.

Important to note - these are subjects sending in samples not timed trial visits where samples would have been taken on the same day or thereabouts. For instance time point 1 for one subject could be 1995, time point 1 for another subject 1996, the difference between timepoint 1 and timepoint 2 is also not consistent. There is an average of around 5 years, however max is 15, min is .5 years.

I have 43, 45, and 42 subjects respectively in each group. My response variable would be say metabolite 1, the predictor would be Group. I also have covariates I would like to be accounted for such as age, BMI, and gender. I would also need to account for family ID (which I have as a random effect in my lmer model). My column with Time has a 0 to mark the time point 1 and 1 is timepoint 2). I understand I must segregate the within and between subjects command, however, I am unsure how to do this. From my understanding so far;

If I am using the anova_test, my formula that needs to be specified for between subjects would be;

```
   Metabolite1 ~ Group*Time
```

Whilst for within subjects ( seeing whether there is any difference within each group at TP1 vs TP2), I am unsure how I would specify this ( the below is not correct).

```
   Metabolite1 ~ Time + Error(ID/Time)
```

The question is, how do I combine this altogether to specify the between and within subject comparisons I would like and accounting for the covariates such as gender, age and BMI? I am assuming if I specify covariates it will become an ANCOVA not an ANOVA?

Some example code that I found that had both a between and within subject comparison design (termed mixed anova).

```
aov1 <- aov(Recall~(Task*Valence*Gender*Dosage)+Error(Subject/(Task*Valence))+(Gender*Dosage),ex5)
```

Where he specifies that the within subject comparison is within the Error term. Also explained here https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/rstatix/reference/anova_test.html

However, mine, which I realise is very wrong currently ( is missing a correct within subject comparison).

```
  repmes<-anova_test(data=mets, Metabolite1~ Group*Time + Error(ID/Time), covariate=c("Age", "BMI", 
  "Gender", "FamilyID")
```

I ultimately would like to determine from this with appropriate post hoc tests ( if p < 0.05) whether there are any significant differences in Metabolite 1 expression between groups between the two time points (i.e over time), and whether there are any significant differences between subjects comparing TP1 with TP2. Please can anybody help.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you seek recommendations for statistical modeling, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: You have to check whether your dataset is balanced before running the repeated measure anova. Also, if the time points are different, I don't think it works for type III. Most likely a type II anova is ok for what you need. You might get better help from cross validated, but i suggest focusing your question on 1 problem, so that you increasing your chances of getting an answer

Comment: @StupidWolf  Thank you for your comment. If possible, please could you quickly elaborate on making sure the data set is balanced for running the repeated measures anova? I think it might be better to run the between and within comparisons separately maybe. Yes, somebody I know with a similar problem but looking at genes not metabolites has posted it on Cross Validated.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit vague. So in your situation, you need to have a time point 1 and time point 2 for every observation, no missing data. I guess most likely you have that. So you can try whether this ```Metabolite1~ Group*Time + Error(ID/Group*Time)```  works

Comment: The Error like you said is an individual correction term.. And this should account for most. If this is ok, try adding in the rest of the covariates. try the aov() first.. anova_test is super quirky